# Error with the keyboard on a WebView - when the keyboard is shown, it causes a white background

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

When i show comment facebook to my app, result below. But when i click to comment 
filed, webview show background white when set keyboard android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan". Sometime, it is cause when scroll webview bottom.

[image: This is normal when i has't to click]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have to found solve with scroll parent view with bottom view when key board visible.

```
  KeyboardVisibilityEvent.setEventListener(
                getActivity(),
                new KeyboardVisibilityEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onVisibilityChanged(boolean isOpen) {
                        // some code depending on keyboard  status
                        if ((isOpen) &&(getUserVisibleHint())) {
                            if (nestVPageDetail != null) {
                                nestVPageDetail.post(new Runnable() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                        if ((nestVPageDetail != null) && (rvContentArrayDetail != null)) {
                                            nestVPageDetail.scrollTo(0,
                                                                     rvContentArrayDetail.getBottom());
                                        }
                                    }
                                });

                            }
                        }

                    }
                });
```

This is lib  check keyboard:

> ```
> implementation 'net.yslibrary.keyboardvisibilityevent:keyboardvisibilityevent:2.1.0'
> ```